# Combine two arrays of objects by key and push values of second array into new array inside first array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need a result Array which containts the data of both arrays. If the name is the same, add the value of the second array into an array of the first array. What would be the best way to do this?

```
var array1 = [
  {name: "name1", type: "type"},
  {name: "name2", type: "type"},
  {name: "name3", type: "type"}
]

var array2 = [
  {name: "name1", value: "value1"},
  {name: "name2", value: "value2"},
  {name: "name2", value: "value3"},
  {name: "name2", value: "value4"}
]

var result = [
  {name: "name1", type: "type", values: [
    "value1"
  ]},
  {name: "name2", type: "type", values: [
    "value2",
    "value3",
    "value4"
  ]},
  {name: "name3", type: "type", values:[]}
]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! All that has been posted is a program description. However, we need you to [ask a question](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). We can't be sure what you want from us. Please [edit] your post to include a valid question that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know [what is on-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), asking us to write the program for you and suggestions are off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my approach (note that it modifies `array1`):

```js
var array1 = [
  {name: "name1", type: "type"},
  {name: "name2", type: "type"},
  {name: "name3", type: "type"}
]

var array2 = [
  {name: "name1", value: "value1"},
  {name: "name2", value: "value2"},
  {name: "name2", value: "value3"},
  {name: "name2", value: "value4"}
]

var result = array1.map(item => {
  item.values = array2
    .filter(x => x.name === item.name)
    .map(x => x.value)
    
  return item
})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

A single-line solution based on ES6 Array.prototype [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?v=a) methods and on [spread opearator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator):

```
const result = array1.map(a1 => ({...a1, values: 
  array2.reduce((r, a2) => a2.name === a1.name ? [...r, a2.value] : r, [])
}));
```

And the version without spread operator but with ES6 [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```
const result = array1.map(a1 => Object.assign({}, a1, { values: 
  array2.reduce((r, a2) => a2.name === a1.name ? r.push(a2.value) && r : r, [])
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Array.prototype.map(), Array.prototype.filter() and ES6 spread operator to do the trick.

```js
var array1 = [
  {name: "name1", type: "type"},
  {name: "name2", type: "type"},
  {name: "name3", type: "type"}
]

var array2 = [
  {name: "name1", value: "value1"},
  {name: "name2", value: "value2"},
  {name: "name2", value: "value3"},
  {name: "name2", value: "value4"}
]

let result = array1.map(item1 => ({
  ...item1,
  values: array2
    .filter(item2 => item2.name === item1.name)
    .map(item2 => item2.value)
}));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

This gives you everything except the empty array where name is `name3` , you could easily add this by looping over every element of array1 and add an empty array.

```js
var array1 = [
  {name: "name1", type: "type"},
  {name: "name2", type: "type"},
  {name: "name3", type: "type"}
];

var array2 = [
  {name: "name1", value: "value1"},
  {name: "name2", value: "value2"},
  {name: "name2", value: "value3"},
  {name: "name2", value: "value4"}
];

for(let i = 0; i < array2.length; i++){
  let data = array2[i];
  for(let j = 0; j < array1.length; j++){
    if(array1[j].name == array2[i].name){
      if(array1[j].value == undefined) array1[j].value = [];
      array1[j].value.push(array2[i].value);

    }
  }
}

console.log(array1);
```